# Python: turn java for loop to python

Tags: java, python, loops, for-loop, range

*how to do flowing for in python : I am interested to do the code below which is in java for python... how to do such for loop in python... thank you
Java solution is like that and works:

```
   for (int=1;i<arr.length;i+=2{
       if(i==arr.length-1){
          if(arr[i]-min>=k)
            return count+1;
          else
            return arr.length;
        }
        else{
         if (arr[i]-min>=k)||(arr[i+1]-min>=k{
          return count+1;
          }
          else
           count++;
           }
          }
        return arr.length;
        } 
    }

    


Python solution is like that and does not work, because ifs and else... 
any ideas, how to do those if else elif..I am a bit confused as there is no {}
```

```
def maxMin(k, arr):
  count=1
  min = arr[0]
  print (min)

for i in range (1, len(arr), 2):
  if i==len(arr)-1:
    if arr[i]-min>=k:
        return count
    else:
        return  len(arr)   
    if (arr[i]-min>=k) or (arr[i+1]-min>=k):
        return count+1
    else:
        return count
    return len(arr)
```

Comment: `for i in range (1, len(arr), 2):`

Comment: thank you, seems working but now is blocked some where else in the code, see above..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i misunderstood your code at first.
I reimplemented your java code in python :

```py
def maxMin(k, min):
    count = 1
    min = arr[0]
    print(min)
    arrlen = len(arr)
    for i in range(1, arrlen, 2):
        if i == arrlen - 1:
            if arr[i] - min >= k:
                return count + 1
            else:
                return arrlen
        else:
            if (arr[i] - min >= k) or (arr[i + 1] - min >= k):
                return count + 1
            else:
                count += 1
    return arrlen
```

The syntax in python for if-elif-else is :

```py
if condition:
    ...
elif condition2:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

And the syntax of your java code is wrong, too, i fixed it for you:

```java
    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        if (i == arr.length - 1) {
            if (arr[i] - min >= k) {
                return count + 1;
            } else {
                return arr.length;
            }
        } else {
            if (arr[i] - min >= k) || (arr[i + 1] - min >= k) {
                return count+1;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr.length;
```

I though cannot guarantee that the code does what you want, because your original code was bit of a mess ;)

Comment: Pas de problème, et bien d'entendre qu'il fonctionne !

Comment: merci, je ne sais pas pour quelle raison mon comment avand est disparu mais cest marche bien

Answer (score 1):

so now it works, thank you frederic, the end code is :

```py
def minimum_points(k, arr):
    count = 1
    min = arr[0]
    print(min)
    arrlen = len(arr)
    for i in range(1, arrlen, 2):
        if i == arrlen - 1:
            if arr[i] - min >= k:
                 return count + 1
            else:
                arrlen
        else:
            if (arr[i] - min >= k) or (arr[i + 1] - min >= k):
                return count + 1
            else:
                count += 1
    return arrlen
```

what it does is :
minimum_points(12, [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 14, 15, 18]) == 4

Answer (score 0):

For your second error : elif is the equivalent of else if in python. 
And on top of that you cannot use else if without a if before. 
You must also know that all the code after your first else statement will never be reached. If your first if is not satisfied it will always go in your else and you make a return in there so it will stop your loop. 
A typic structure would be : if elif else